# ROS fuerte rosmake -std=c++11 compile error

Tags: c++11, ros

I was trying to compile a node that uses a library that needs c++11 flag (It uses std::function and nullptr among other features).

Here is de outpulog: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mr8gltnrdn1...

But summarizing:

```
               from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:62,
               from /usr/include/c++/4.8/algorithm:62,
               from /usr/include/boost/math/tools/config.hpp:16,
               from /usr/include/boost/math/special_functions/round.hpp:13,
               from /opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/time.h:58,
               from /opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/ros.h:38,
               from /home/bardo91/programming/EC-SAFEMOBIL/ros/PatrollingCV/uav_vision/src/uav_vision_node.cpp:9:
 /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_construct.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::_Construct(_T1*, _Args&& ...) [with _T1 = actionlib_msgs::GoalStatus_<std::allocator<void> >; _Args = {actionlib_msgs::GoalStatus_<std::allocator<void> >&}]’:
   /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:75:53:   required from ‘static _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy<_TrivialValueTypes>::__uninit_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = actionlib_msgs::GoalStatus_<std::allocator<void> >*; _ForwardIterator = actionlib_msgs::GoalStatus_<std::allocator<void> >*; bool _TrivialValueTypes = false]’

 /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:117:41:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = actionlib_msgs::GoalStatus_<std::allocator<void> >*; _ForwardIterator = actionlib_msgs::GoalStatus_<std::allocator<void> >*]’
  /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:258:63:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = actionlib_msgs::GoalStatus_<std::allocator<void> >*; _ForwardIterator = actionlib_msgs::GoalStatus_<std::allocator<void> >*; _Tp = actionlib_msgs::GoalStatus_<std::allocator<void> >]’
```

And so on... It's not only for the library, I would like to use new features of c++, but I don't know what to do to fix it. Can anybody help me?

Thank in advance

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully used the following line in my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11")
```

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem. I use 'rosbuild_add_compile_flags(command_uav_node "-std=c++11")' that has the same effect. The error came from <ros/ros.h>. Could it be because I'm using ROS fuerte and it could be compiled without c++11 flags?

Comment: @Bardo91: What compiler do you use? For older GCC versions (<= 4.6) it is `-std=c++0x`.

Comment: I've installed gcc-4.8. If you askme what compiler is using "rosmake" I don't know. I'm compiling using rosmake that as far as I concern use a CmakeList (in which file I set the flag) file as configuration and use the gcc compiler of the computer (That should be gcc-4.8).